# How to write results to only one file in test suite selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following Test Suite code. This triggers the individual tests in the set. The problem is output to the html file. Suite creates a separate file for each test.

Would anyone know how to write results to only one file?

````
import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner
from check_password import PasswordTest
from check_username import test_Administration

class suite_test(unittest.TestSuite):
    suite1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(PasswordTest)
    suite2 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(test_Administration)

    all_tests = unittest.TestSuite([suite1, suite2])

html_report_dir = './html_report'
#unittest.TextTestRunner().run(all_tests)
unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output=html_report_dir))```
````

Answer (score 1):

Just add to the HTMLTestRunner:

```
unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output=html_report_dir, combine_reports=True))
```

This will combine all your Tests results to one page. 
 
For further reading O suggest you will read the package docs
https://github.com/oldani/HtmlTestRunner
There are some very useful tips there regarding this package like setting name for the report result and more.

Good day!

Comment: I am glad it helped, do you know how to accept an answer?https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work